# NextAuth.js - Credentials signIn always returns ok=true when redirect=false

Tags: typescript, next.js, next-auth

I am trying to create a custom login page with NextAuth but I have trouble with the `signIn` function.
It always returns `ok=true` even if credentials does not match (email & password).

Note that it works when redirect is set to true, but setting it to false cause this problem.
It also works great when using the built-in signIn page with NextAuth.

I used the debugger and checked if my `authorize` function was working correctly but it does. Even when it hits a `return null`, I still get `ok=true`

Code (tried to simplify it) :

Login page.tsx

```js
'use client';

export default async function Login() {
    async function onSubmit(event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) {
        event.preventDefault();

        const formData = new FormData(event.currentTarget);
        const email = formData.get("email");
        const password = formData.get("password");

        const { error, ok, status } = await signIn("credentials", {
            email: email,
            password: password,
            redirect: false,
        });

        console.log(ok); // Always true
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={onSubmit} method="post">
            <Stack spacing={1} marginX="auto" width="50vw">
                <TextField variant="standard" required type="email" name="email" label="Mail" />
                <TextField variant="standard" required type="password" name="password" label="Mot de passe" />
                <Button variant="contained" type="submit">Connexion</Button>
            </Stack>
        </form>
    )

}
```

AuthProvider.tsx

```js
'use client';

import { SessionProvider } from 'next-auth/react';

type Props = {
    children: React.ReactNode;
};

export default function AuthProvider({ children }: Props) {
    return (
        <SessionProvider>
            {children}
        </SessionProvider>
    )
```

/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts

```js
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import { prisma } from "@/lib/db";

export const authOptions = {
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
    pages: {
        signIn: "/login"
    },
    providers: [
        CredentialsProvider({
            credentials: {
                email: { label: "email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
                password: { label: "password", type: "password", placeholder: "Mot de passe" }
            },
            async authorize(credentials, req) {
                const loginEmail = credentials?.email;
                const loginPass = credentials?.password;
                
                const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({ where: { email: loginEmail } });

                if (!user) {
                    return null
                }

                if (user.password === loginPass) {
                    return { id: String(user.id), email: user.email }
                }

                return null
            }
        })
    ]
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

Versions:

- NextJs: 13.4.4
- NextAuth: 4.22.1

Tried to add NEXTAUTH_URL & NEXTAUTH_SECRET in env.
Used debugger to pinpoint an error in my code.

ok should be false when the credentials does not match user data in DB, or when authorize returns null

Comment: related (according to a non-answer posted as an answer): https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth/issues/7725